# Emulator not displaying any controls, need help!

Tags: android-emulator

I am new to android development.
I have added some controls in main.xml but they fail to show up on the emulator.
Please tell me what am I doing wrong.
Here is my xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center">

 <TextView   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:gravity="center" android:text="@string/app_name"          
           android:textSize="30dp"/>

<EditText android:id="@+id/editable"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android.Text="Text goes here " android:layout_weight="1" android:hint="@string/display"/>       

<Button     android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:text="@string/mainPageButton" 
            android:textSize="25dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

in your onCreate method in your activity?